# What should I do in this game?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm playing this game but I'm not sure what to do. What should I do?

[image]

Hint:

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should...

> **WIN!**
>
>  The cube shows a [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html)-style encoding of each guess, which is the value of the cards to the right. There are no letters of "ACE", there is a "W" from "TWO", but in a different place, and the "N" from "TEN" is in the right place.
>
>   From the hint, the "I" from "SIX" is also in the correct place, which confirms that the solution is "WIN".

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you should:

> **Twist!**
>
>  Because you're never going to win Rubik's Pontoon with that cube/hand combo.
>
>  (For anyone unfamiliar with it, Pontoon is a card game very similar to Blackjack where the aim is to get as close to (but not over) 21. In Pontoon you "twist" to get another card (where you would "hit" in Blackjack.)

Comment: This is not the intended solution... but I learned a new game so thank you.